# YourTheme_links doesn't work on sub theme

Tags: navigation

I have tried the way described in http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_link/7#comment-24463

But as it seems it works on the main theme but not on a subtheme.

```
function MYTHEME_link($variables) {
    print_r($variables);
    die;
}
```

Yeilds no result.

Applied on Zen theme which results the menus.

But on a subtheme it shows nothing. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you using the sub theme as your primary theme? Is it enabled?

Comment: Both yes. I am using the subtheme as primary and enabled.

Comment: Is it in the subtheme's template file or Zen's?

Comment: Its in subtheme's template.

Comment: Does your MYTHEME.info have the tag base theme="" set? Cache cleared? :)

Comment: @PontusNilsson yes for both. Base theme is `zen` and cache cleared so many times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a typo, the function should be `MYTHEME_link` and not `MYTHEME_links`.Possible other ways to identify is use theme engine `phptemplate_link` instead of your theme name.

Try clearing your theme registry. Also Check whether you have spelled your theme machine name correctly.

```
function MYTHEME_link($variables) {
    print_r($variables);
    die;
}
```

Comment: I have checked the same with zen theme as main and it worked but not when I call the same with subtheme.

Comment: And also I had the typo, not what I have tried. As it worked for Zen theme it should have worked on sub theme also.

I'll give it a try with `phptemplate_link` and let you know.